# Audio drift in Premiere (not VFR)

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm getting audio drift in Premiere, and it's not related (or is it?) to VFR. I honestly really dont know where this is coming from, but, oh God, Premiere… Obviously, when I read the file in VLC or any other player, it's fine. But in Premiere…

Here's my media informations :

```
General
Complete name                            : /Users/petaire/Desktop/LCI-2019-10-16_10-00-00h.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 831 MiB
Duration                                 : 2h 0mn
Overall bit rate                         : 968 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf57.83.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2h 0mn
Bit rate                                 : 832 Kbps
Width                                    : 900 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.051
Stream size                              : 715 MiB (86%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 152 r2854 e9a5903
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=16 / lookahead_threads=5 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=10 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 1h 59mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 129 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 111 MiB (13%)
Language                                 : French
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

Premiere…

I think it might be related to this line :

```
Frame rate                               : 46.875 fps (1024 SPF)
```

I'm using this line for ffmpeg encoding :

```
ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i $1 -preset veryfast -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=-1:720 -threads $numberOfThreads $2
```

Do you know how to force SPF to 25FPS (of the SPF equivalent)?

Comment: How much drift? Does the amount change? When does it start? Premiere version?

Comment: Audio FPS is not the issue - it's normal.

Comment: The drift change all along the file, and I'm up to date in Premiere Pro…
Right now I'm trying with -async 1 -vsync 1, it's promising, but…

Comment: You may try `ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i $1 -preset veryfast -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -vf scale=-1:720 -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0 -threads $numberOfThreads $2`